# How is a vptr initialized at compile time?

Tags: c++

The above was an interview question.

I understand that as part of the virtual dispatch mechanism, the compiler creates a `vTable` for each class and inserts an extra pointer (`vptr`) during compilation. But when exactly does it assign the class' virtual table to this `vptr`?

How is the `vptr` initialized at compile time?

Whatever I read over the internet says that the compiler initializes the `vptr` at compile time, but initialization is a run-time mechanism. Am I wrong?

I don't understand how a compiler would initialize it.

Comment: The contents of the vtable are "initialized at compile time" in a similar way to `const` POD data, or at least they become part of the program image and don't need any code to initialize.  But yes, the vptr which points at part of the vtable must be initialized at runtime in the constructor of every object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strictly speaking, this is not covered by the C++ standard. But enough implementations go for this to consider it common wisdom. I'm going to address only single inheritance, since multiple inheritance is way more complicated.

The compiler knows in advance where a type's virtual function table is located (it's the compiler that allocates it). It also knows all of that class type's constructors. So what it has to do is fairly simple, at the beginning of each constructor, add the following (illustrative):

```
this->_vptr = /*VTable's Address*/;
```

That's it. This is exceptionally simple, and even works intuitively when overriding. Because a derived class's constructor will just overwrite the pointer value.

And yes, that assignment, naturally, happens at run-time. Even though the table itself may be populated beforehand.

Comment: Bonus: this ties in nicely with the mandated fact that virtual function calls from a constructor are dispatched to the *current* type, not the eventual most derived one. The constructors are run from least to most derived, each one overwriting the vptr in turn, and it "just works".

Comment: @Quentin - And that's just even if a compiler chooses to make you pay for it, and not resolve it statically. Though it kinda has to dispatch statically in the destructor. Otherwise it'll be UB all the way.

Comment: Well, the destructor can simply reset the `vptr` to its base class's v-table before calling through to its base class's destructor. That would invert the process of construction quite nicely.

Comment: Of course, the whole vptr overwriting is not needed when the compiler can determine the `vptr` isn't used in the ctor and will be overwritten of a more-derived class (which can be visible due to inlining)